# How to solve the following case?

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery, subquery

Consider the following question:
We have 3 tables,

```
1. Theatre  ( theatre_Id, thatre_name )
2. ShowTime ( showTimeId,  theatre_Id, movie_id )
3. Movies   ( movie_id, movie_name )
```

Now same movie name can also have different movieId's sort of dependent on the reel.

Eg: [1, HarryPotter], [2, HarryPotter], [3, Pirates of Carr]

Now we need to find movie name which has showtime on all theatre locations ?
Is it nested correlated query ?

Comment: which sql database and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you explain in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you better phrase the question:

> What are the names of movies whose theatre list is the same size as the number of theatres?

you get the query:

```
select distinct movie_name
from Movies m
where movie_id in (
    select movie_id
    from ShowTime
    group by movie_id
    having count(distinct theatre_Id) = (select count(*) from Theatre))
```

Comment: how can we do it using 'exists' ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper why would you want to? This will out-perform `exists` by a great deal: O(n) vs O(n^2)