# Solving in quadratic time?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following question: We have 3 tables,

1. Theatre  ( theatre_Id, thatre_name )
2. ShowTime ( showTimeId,  theatre_Id, movie_id )
3. Movies   ( movie_id, movie_name )
   Now same movie name can also have different movieId's sort of dependent on the reel.

Eg: [1, HarryPotter], [2, HarryPotter], [3, Pirates of Carr]

This question was answered before.
[How to solve the following nested query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424707/how-to-solve-the-following-nested-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the same formula with no regard of the logic but using EXISTS instead of IN

```
select distinct movie_name
from Movies m
where EXISTS (
    select 1
    from ShowTime t
    where m.movie_id = t.movie_id
    group by movie_id
    having count(distinct theatre_Id) = (select count(*) from Theatre))
```